# S3 upload fails in production (Python)

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm trying to upload an XML file to S3 in my Django app.

I have tried tinys3, boto3, and boto original flavor.

tinys3 worked like a charm in localhost, but if I'm even importing the file when I load it with Elastic Beanstalk I get an error much like what I get from boto3 when I do the same (except boto3 lets me get as far as launching the server and initiating the xml upload from the client):

```
invalid syntax (_base.py, line 381)
```

With the tinys3 imported, I get this error (again, only on elastic beanstalk):

```
[Fri Nov 17 00:51:28.918531 2017] [:error] [pid 32767]   File "/opt/python/current/app/user_package/views.py", line 22, in <module>
[Fri Nov 17 00:51:28.918533 2017] [:error] [pid 32767]     import tinys3
[Fri Nov 17 00:51:28.918534 2017] [:error] [pid 32767]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tinys3/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
[Fri Nov 17 00:51:28.918536 2017] [:error] [pid 32767]     from .pool import Pool
[Fri Nov 17 00:51:28.918537 2017] [:error] [pid 32767]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tinys3/pool.py", line 4, in <module>
[Fri Nov 17 00:51:28.918539 2017] [:error] [pid 32767]     from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed
[Fri Nov 17 00:51:28.918540 2017] [:error] [pid 32767]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/concurrent/futures/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
[Fri Nov 17 00:51:28.918542 2017] [:error] [pid 32767]     from concurrent.futures._base import (FIRST_COMPLETED,
[Fri Nov 17 00:51:28.918543 2017] [:error] [pid 32767]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 381
[Fri Nov 17 00:51:28.918545 2017] [:error] [pid 32767]     raise exception_type, self._exception, self._traceback
[Fri Nov 17 00:51:28.918547 2017] [:error] [pid 32767]                         ^
[Fri Nov 17 00:51:28.918549 2017] [:error] [pid 32767] SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Boto original doesn't work at all.

I definitely need the ability to upload XML's dynamically to S3.
No idea why this won't work.

Comment: What happens if you deploy a minimal Python/Django app and import boto3?

Comment: So that seems to work...

Comment: Looks like https://github.com/agronholm/pythonfutures/issues/41

Answer (score -1):

Works for me with AWS Command line tools

> aws s3 cp ~/myFiles/file.xml < s3 URI > --recursive

Comment: Yeah, I need to be able to do it from within my application